# How can I draw a rectangular grid connecting the points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe say named dfResultGrid with data as shown below.

```
dfResultGrid <- structure(list(x = c(3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5, 5, 7, 9, 11, 6.5, 8.5, 
10.5, 12.5, 8, 10, 12, 14), y = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```

Ok
As per the discussion I am adding the code to get the above dataframe

```
BaseMatrix <- matrix(c(2, 1, 1.5, 2), nrow = 2)
dfGrid <- expand.grid(x=1:4, y=1:4)
pointMat <- t(as.matrix(dfGrid))
ResultMat <- BaseMatrix %*% pointMat
dfResultGrid <- as.data.frame(t(ResultMat))
```

A scatter plot of the 16 points are well distributed

```
ggplot(dfResultGrid, aes(x= x, y= y)) +
  geom_point()
```

How can I draw a grid like surface connecting those points ( parallel lines connecting the points).
Geom_tile did not help in this case.

Expected plot is as given below.
[image]
Thanks so much.

Comment: `+ geom_path()` connects all of the points, as does `+ geom_line()`. The order is specific to them: `geom_path` orders by the order in the data, `geom_line` orders by the `x` value.

Comment: 'geom_path()' in fact only draw a line connecting all the points. Can you please suggests how to get a grid kind structure. parallel lines intersecting at the grid points.

Comment: That isn't clear to me, sorry. Can you demonstrate what that looks like in your question? You might simplify the data to fewer points and then create the plot with individual raw commands ... or just a napkin-sketch (that is close-enough to your sample data).

Comment: Thanks. I just added an expected plot of the data.

Comment: Interesting question. Two questions for clarification - are those points always going to be perfectly regular? How do you generate those grids? Any "other information" available, in particular location of the points within the grid? (e.g., 2nd point on the horizontal, 3rd on the vertical meridian)

Comment: Yes, the points in this case are going to be perfectly regular because I generate these points using a matrix multiplication to a 2D array data. The grids were generated as a sample in hand drawn tool for adding clarity to the question.

Comment: This could maybe help to generate the grid - could you maybe try to generate those points in the example in a similar way, please? Ideally also including dim names for your arrays if you have

Comment: Dear @tjebo I have added the code for generating the data frame<dfResultGrid> as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Also using geom_segment, but here a more programmatic way. I have used the information that you were creating the grid based on a previous grid expansion and then matrix multiplication.

The code could certainly be shortened, especially the head/tail bits, but I left it like this for clarity.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# you have used "expand grid" on a pattern of nxn
n <- 4
# your coordinate creation, slightly modified (using "n")
BaseMatrix <- matrix(c(2, 1, 1.5, 2), nrow = 2)
pointMat <- t(expand.grid(x = 1:n, y = 1:n))
ResultMat <- BaseMatrix %*% pointMat
dfResultGrid <- as.data.frame(t(ResultMat))
names(dfResultGrid) <- c("x", "y")

# Get coordinates for bottom and left points as segment start
pt_base <- head(dfResultGrid, n)
pt_left <- dfResultGrid[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, n-1)), ]
# Get coordinates for top and right points as segment end
pt_top <- tail(dfResultGrid, n)
names(pt_top) <- c("xend", "yend")
pt_right <- dfResultGrid[c(rep(FALSE, n-1), TRUE), ]
names(pt_right) <- c("xend", "yend")
# cbind xend/yend to x/y, and rbind vertical to horizontal segment coordinates
df_seg <- rbind(cbind(pt_base, pt_top), cbind(pt_right, pt_left))

ggplot(dfResultGrid, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = df_seg, aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: A very thoughtful one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_segment()` to connect two points only. The following code can produce your desired segments.

```
ggplot(dfResultGrid, aes(x= x, y= y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[1], y = y[1], xend = x[13], yend =y[13])) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[1], y = y[1], xend = x[4], yend =y[4]))   + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[2], y = y[2], xend = x[14], yend =y[14])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[3], y = y[3], xend = x[15], yend =y[15])) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[4], y = y[4], xend = x[16], yend =y[16])) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[5], y = y[5], xend = x[8], yend =y[8]))  + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[9], y = y[9], xend = x[12], yend =y[12])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x[13], y = y[13], xend = x[16], yend =y[16]))
```

[image]

I don't know a smarter way to do this, but I found that in base R we can get the almost the same result with more efficient code.

```
k = 1: nrow(mygrid)-1
plot(dfResultGrid, pch = 19); 

with(dfResultGrid, segments(x[k], y[k], x[k+4], y[k+4]) + 
     segments(x[4], y[4], x[16], y[16]) +  
     segments(x[1], y[1], x[13], y[13])  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a more smarter way to do this.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I am sorry I don't know smarter way than that.

Comment: This is nicer one. Although the lines intersecting fashion is little different then the original one, its useful. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry. You're right.  Glad if it is useful.